# Security questions about cookies and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, security, cookies

Ok, i have always wondered if these 2 actions are possible:

1. To manipulate cookies. I mean, if i login for example into facebook it will save a cookie in my browser. Could i edit it in anyway? I think so since it is set into MY browser and not set locally.
2. To manipulare a javascript script. I mean, since javascript is read by the browser and every user can read the language, could it be edited? For example, let's say i have an ajax call that send data strings like `user=basic` or something (it's just an example), could someone change it to `user=admin`?

I hope this kind of things are not possible or i am pretty much f****d!

Comment: Pigarelli welcome to the Internet, 2011 AD.

Comment: Doesn't nobody think that making cookies and javascript protected could save thousands of useless line of code?

Comment: It's just not possible to do that without imposing a completely different set of rules for the Internet and for personal computers in general. In today's world, you have to hand over your content to the end user equipment for it to be shown on the screen. So long as there are things like open-source web browsers (and whole operating systems), you don't control enough of the user equipment to allow content to be secured.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that case, I'm sorry to say you are pretty much f****d.

You must always assume that *everything* on the client side can be manipulated by some evil hacker. This includes cookies and JavaScript.

Firefox makes this extra easy, using the [Edit Cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/edit-cookies/) extension for cookies, and [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to edit JavaScript (and HTML and CSS).

Comment: Why haven't nobody fixed this? I mean, i don't know, sending security hash or stuff? It's unbelievable! Also could session be manipulated too?

Comment: Sessions are the fix for this. Sessions are handled by setting a session ID cookie, and all the data in the session is stored server-side by that ID. They can change the ID in the cookie, but session IDs are made non-guessable for that reason.

Comment: Nobody "fixed" it because it's impossible to fix. Indeed, people work around it by (you guessed it) "sending security hashes or stuff" :) For example, a session token (which might be just a random huge number) is stored in the cookie, and is used on the server side to retrieve session data. Because the session data lives on the server, it cannot be manipulated by evil hackers (we hope!).

Comment: Also worth noting is the very handy [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) plugin for Firefox (and maybe Chrome). That lets the browser user mess with all the details of any HTTP request.

Answer (score 2):

Both users and javascript can manipulate cookie data. However, broswers have optional (maybe default) protection against setting cookie data cross-domain.

Comment: It's possible to POST to any server on the internet with any cookies you want. Now, getting working *values* for the cookies, that's another story, but you can *always* craft an HTTP request with arbitrary contents.

Comment: @charlie - I wouldn't set sensitive data in cookies.  I think it smart to set a hash (or key) that refers to a server side session entry which hold sensitive data.

Comment: Are there any tutorials about this hash system?

Comment: http://www.learnphp-tutorial.com/Sessions.cfm or http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html.    Other languages would have similiar tutorials

Comment: @josh - Using a small integer as the key into the server side session is not a good idea.  A cryptographic hash (md5 or similiar) would make manually manipulating the session key unlikely to succeed.

Answer (score 2):

I think modifying cookies should be pretty easy, as they're stored locally. I checked and in firefox there's a bunch of sqlite files that seem to have that. I don't know much about sqlite, but it seems that modifying them should not be a problem (especially since you could get to the browser source code in this case and see how it interacts with them :) )

I'm not sure about javascript modification, it most surely can be done by messing around with low level HTTP stuff (intercepting request and sending bogus responses with the modified code). Anti cross-site scripting policies helps a little, but I wouldn't rely on them much, there should be security checks server based to be safer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes/No, your domain can only manipulate cookies set by your domain. Your JS script, being on `youdomain.com` or `localhost` cannot edit a cookie set by `facebook.com`. Think about it, Internet would have imploded by now if you could do that.

   However, users can edit their cookies at will.
2. Yes.

Comment: While you're right about script on one domain seeing or changing the cookies of another domain, you've missed the question.  I, as the end user, **can** edit the cookies on my machine.  While there's usually no value in doing so, it would allow a user to bypass the security of a poorly designed system.  (IE, where the cookie just stores `uid=1234` -- change the uid to `1` and suddenly you're an admin!)

Comment: Wait what? If i login into facebook and facebook set a cookie i cannot edit it? Josh got my question.

Comment: I was just clarifying, users can edit their cookies at will, that's true, however a JS script can't. I just thought it was relevant to Charlie as web developer concerned about this kind of stuff. I'll change my "no" by a "yes/no".

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

- Validate the data client-side for usability, but also do it server-side to prevent someone from tampering with the data
- Encrypt cookies to make it harder to manipulate

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes, and there are even [tools specifically designed to make doing so easy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privoxy).  Getting security right is hard, and unfortunately it's something that greener web developers often completely miss.

The only thing you can really safely store in a cookie is a login ***token***.  Basically, each time your user logs in, generate something like a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier).  Save the GUID to a column in the user's record (like `LoginToken` or whatever) and then set their cookie to the same GUID.  When they logout, clear the record's `LoginToken`.  Then when a request comes in, you can just query your database for the user who has a `LoginToken` equal to the value in the cookie.  It's safe to assume that by holding the token, the requestor is in fact the user represented by the token.

If a malicious user edits their cookie, they'll get nothing more than logged out, since you'd treat a not-found token the same as no token at all.

On the server, once you check a token, you *then* determine if that user has admin rights (usually by looking at their record).

As far as being able to modify script, that's just a fact of life.  Your **server code has to assume that every request is malicious**.  Before you do *anything*, verify their token and verify that they're allowed to do what they're requesting.